# JavaScript Surround quotes around a single string in multi lines

Tags: javascript, regex

My string is somewhat like this :

```
<rules>
  <transTypeRuleList>
    <transType type='stocks'>
      <criteria result='401kContribution' priority='0'>
        <field compare='contains' name='description'></field>
      </criteria>
      <criteria result='401kContribution' priority='1'>
        <field compare='contains' name='description'></field>
      </criteria>
    </transType>
  </transTypeRuleList>
</rules>
```

I need to take this and paste it in eclipse as a string , I know eclipse has an option to escape multi line strings and all, but that gives me the string as with `"\n \r"` Which I don't want .

My ideal string would be just the Double quotes and a `+` at the end of each line somewhat like this.

```
var res= "<rules>"+
    "<acctTypeRuleList>"+
    "<acctTypetype='stocks'>"+
    "<criteriaresult='individual'priority='0'>"+
    "<fieldcompare='contains'name='accountName'></field>"+
    "</criteria>"+
    "<criteriaresult='individual'priority='1'>"+
    "<fieldcompare='contains'name='accountName'></field>"+
    "</criteria>"+
    "</acctType>"+
    "</acctTypeRuleList>"+
    "<transTypeRuleList>"+
    "<transTypetype='stocks'>"+
    "<criteriaresult='401kContribution'priority='0'>"+
    "<fieldcompare='contains'name='description'></field>"+
    "</criteria>"+
    "<criteriaresult='401kContribution'priority='1'>"+
    "<fieldcompare='contains'name='description'></field>"+
    "</criteria>"+
    "</transType>"+
    "</transTypeRuleList>"+
    "</rules>";
```

While preserving the indentation. So I am looking at regex.

So I guess finding `^(.*)$` and replacing with `"$1" +` should have done the job but it doesn't work .

Have a look at the fiddle. :

[Link](http://www.regexr.com/38prv)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

http://regexr.com/38ps2

What I did

- added the multiline `m` switch
- removed the empty line in the text. Looks like regexr has problems with that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try with this:

```
'var res = "' + xml.replace(/\r?\n\s*/g, '" +\r\n\t"') + '";';
```

But remember that Javascript *does* allow multiline strings. Just put a backslash at the end of each line:

```
"<rules>\
  <transTypeRuleList>\
...\
</rules>";
```